Jenkins active choices from the cli
Is there any way to trigger a pipeline that takes an active choices parameter from the CLI ? I've been trying to figure out how you'd encode the array, but can't get it to work.
jenkins-cli build -v <job> -p MY_PARAM=?

Thanks

Figured it out, it's simply a regular string with each value separated by a ,
jenkins-cli build -v <job> -p MY_PARAM=value1,value2,value3

